# Lots of issues with maven project

Tags: java, maven

I've got a LOT of issues with an imported maven project which I can build, `mvn install` is working great (and the created war is working fine) however when I'm importing it in Eclipse or in VSCode (with all the plugins installed), I've got more than 200 issues.

Example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

is giving me:

> SpringApplication cannot be resolved

And most of the `import` are giving me the same issue

Same problem in my pom with a bunch of `missing artifact`

What I've tried:

- Reinstall IDE's
- MVN install
- MVN clean install

My goal here is to have no issues and be able to run my class by clicking on it and run it from there as the war is creating perfectly fine.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: How have you imported the project in Eclipse?

Comment: Hi @Pino , 
File -> Import -> Existing maven projects -> selected the project's directory

Comment: Clearly Eclipse can't resolve the dependencies. Try a clean within Eclipse then a clean install or something

Answer (score 0):

Import the project in Eclipse, then build it with `clean install` (if the build does not succeed, fix that first), then update the project with ALT+F5 and wait until all Eclipse operations are gone. This usually helps.

Comment: Thanks, however, I've already done that a lot of time without any success

Comment: Then either the project is very strange or your Eclipse is broken.